# Fetch the data from Power BI related to username/emailId by whom Azure Pipeline was ran

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-pipelines, powerbi-desktop

"https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRuns?"

Using this url I am able to fetch RunNumber, RunReason but unable to fetch RunBy which user.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I tried to get the odata feed "https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/PipelineRuns" in Power BI, currently there is no option to fetch who trigger the pipeline. And check the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is also without this.

You could use "Request a feature" on the left side of [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to open a new suggestion ticket.

For more information about who trigger the pipeline, you could refer to this.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the user that requested the run using predefined variables.

```
$(Build.RequestedFor)
```

And additionally you can also use

```
echo $(Build.RequestedForEmail)
echo $(Build.RequestedForId)
```

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#identity_values

There are some predefined variable for RunReason and BuildID as well.

`$(Build.Reason)`
`$(Build.BuildId)`

Comment: Your answer is based on Azure Devops. I need those values in Power BI where my Data Source is Azure Devops

Comment: @Meet consider changing the question to be more accurate so that people can understand the requirement.